# Interaction in a Binomial how interpret

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

So, my doubt is simple, I ran this model:

```
glm(formula = pregnancy ~ Bull*SEMEN, family = binomial(), 
    data = dt)
```

Just 2 bulls (a and b) and 2 semen (s and c) related to pregnancy. And I obtained these results:

```
      Deviance Residuals: 
            Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
        -1.2377  -0.8748  -0.6172   1.1183   1.8720  

      Coefficients:
                         Estimate   Std.Error z value     Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept)             0.1406     0.1878    0.749       0.454067    
 Bulla                  -0.9038     0.2427   -3.724       0.000196 ***
 SEMENs                 -1.7022     0.2749   -6.191       0.00000000596 ***
 Bulla:SEMENs            0.9330     0.3798    2.456       0.014039 *
```

So, I made the exponential:

```
(Intercept)    Bulla          SEMENs         Bulla:SEMENs 
1.1509434      0.4050290      0.1822767      2.5420404
```

For the Bullb has 60% more chance of pregnancy than Bullb, and SEMENc has 70% more chance than SEMENs. Ok, I know, I need consider just the interaction, but the result didn't make sense. Or is there a different way to interpret the interaction? Or this result didn't make sense in this analysis?

A table with additional information:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the proportion of successful pregnancy (depending on bull and semen) in a table?

Comment: @Roland, I made this, thanks.

Comment: From the table you can easily see: (i) Semen s has a lower chance of pregnancy than Semen c, (ii) there is no difference between the bulls for Semen s, (iii) Bull B has a much higher chance of pregnancy than Bull A for Semen c. The model fit agrees with this. Can you explain more clearly what "didn't make sense" to you?

Comment: @Roland, Shouldn't the result be negative for the interaction, and I should consider just the interaction?